# Using LIKE Operator in Validation Rule

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a table called TableA and TableB.

TableA (fieldID, fieldType, fieldNo)

TableB (fieldNo, field1, field2)

TableA - fieldNo is a FK.
TableB - fieldNo is a PK.
fieldType is a combo box consisting of value1 and value2

I want it to only fill in records of fieldNo (in TableA) where fieldType Like "value1" using a validation rule. I tried using "If" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you putting lookup fields in tables? This is almost never a good idea.

Comment: So what do you mean by "fieldType is a combo box consisting of value1 and value2"?

Comment: In TableA, there is a field called fieldType. It is a combo box. That combo box consists of "Value1" and "Value2." And yes, I kept lookup.